# Build Mozilla NSS statically linked

Tags: mozilla, nss, certutil

Has anyone been able to build NSS statically linked?  I actually only need to build certutil and pk12util statically linked.  I've seen that Chromium is building NSS statically, and they even have a patch file, but the whole build process is quite involved and I'm just trying to do a small subset.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mike - I believe Wladimir's answer is correct (I'm not an NSS expert, so I can only admire what he's written). If it is the case, then you should click the check mark to accept his answer so others who visit this page know its the correct answer (even if its not the answer you were hoping for).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is right now, NSS cannot be built statically. There is some work in progress in [bug 534471](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=534471) and [bug 533014](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=533014) (NSS and NSPR respectively) but these patches are quite old and likely don't apply any more. It seems that nobody at Mozilla is currently working on this.

As to Chromium, they are using a heavily patched NSS version. Also, they are using GYP to build NSS, not the Makefiles normally supplied with NSS. You could probably build their NSS version but I'm not sure whether it is really useful outside Chrome. The relevant directories are [deps/third_party/nss/](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/deps/third_party/nss/) and [src/net/third_party/nss/](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/third_party/nss/), former being NSS without libssl and the latter being libssl only.

Comment: If I recall correctly on the NSS site, they were saying you needed VS2010.  However they also had build files made for VS2008 and maybe even a previous version.  This removed the need I had for static linking.  Thanks for your help!  :)